# ACF repeater pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, advanced-custom-fields, image-gallery

I would appreciate some help regarding Advanced Custom Fields repeater. The thing is that I am building a gallery with the plugin but I need pagination at the end of the page. I am displaying the pagination links, but when clicking they don't seem to work. Is it something with the url of the page - it's not showing page number in the url. Here is my code:

```
<?php


/*
 * Paginate Advanced Custom Field repeater
*/

if (get_query_var('paged')) {
    $page = get_query_var('paged');
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

// Variables
$row             = 0;
$images_per_page = 2; // How many images to display on each page
$images          = get_field('thumbnail_image_repeater');
$total           = count($images);
$pages           = ceil($total / $images_per_page);
$min             = (($page * $images_per_page) - $images_per_page) + 1;
$max             = ($min + $images_per_page) - 1;
?> 

 <?php
if (have_rows('thumbnail_image_repeater')):
?> 
   <?php
    while (have_rows('thumbnail_image_repeater')):
        the_row();
        $row++;

        // Ignore this image if $row is lower than $min
        if ($row < $min) {
        continue;
        }

        // Stop loop completely if $row is higher than $max
        if ($row > $max) {
            break;
        }
?>   

 <?php
        $image          = get_sub_field('thumbnail_image');
        $thumbnail_name = get_sub_field('thumbnail_name');
?> 



    <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-responsive="<?php
        echo $image['url'];
?>" data-src="<?php
        echo $image['url'];
?>" data-sub-html="<h4><?php
        echo $thumbnail_name;
?></h4><p><?php
        echo $thumbnail_name;
?></p>" data-pinterest-text="Pin it1" data-tweet-text="share on twitter 1"> 
        <a href=""> 
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php
        echo $image['url'];
?>" alt="Thumb-1" /> 
        </a> 
    </li> 
        <?php
    endwhile;
    // Pagination
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
        'format' => '?page=%#%',
        'current' => $page,
        'total' => $pages,
        'prev_text' => __('<<<'),
        'next_text' => __('>>>')
    ));
?> 


  <?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Try to change the format into 'paged=' instead of 'page='.

Comment: Tried that, but didn't work. Something else is the problem. I suppose something with the url that wordpress doesn't add /2/ at the second page, /3/ at the third page etc.

Comment: Have you tried adding page_url/page/2 instead of just page_url/2? If that does not help, then I can propose a solution for registering your own url rewrites and apply that to your pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an older version of [Jonathan Nicol's Repeater](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/03/06/paginating-an-advanced-custom-fields-repeater/) pagination. The version you're using only functions on regular, built-in pages. I'm betting you're using this on a custom post type. He updated it a few years back to support CPTs. Here's what he had to say:

> The query variable referenced at the start of the code snippet becomes
>   ‘page’ instead of ‘paged’:
>
> ```
> if( get_query_var('page') ) {
>    $page = get_query_var( 'page' );
> } else {
>    $page = 1;
> }
> ```
>
> And the base and format options passed to paginate_links become:
>
> ```
> 'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
> 'format' => '?page=%#%',
> ```

Comment: Hi Leland, I tried this before, but still didn't work. The thing is that I've read that you use 'paged' instead of 'page' because the second one relates only to the home page, and you use 'paged' for every other page. However, I see that in the blog you've mentioned that 'WordPress automagically converts URL segments such as /2/ into a query variable named "page".' When I go to the second page, for example, my url does not convert in url/2/, but it goes straight to the gallery slider and the images that are on the next pages are not visible, only the small img icon appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php







/**



 * Template Name: Testimonial Page



*/











get_header(); ?>











<?php if(function_exists('demo_custom_innner_banner_code')) demo_custom_innner_banner_code(); ?>



 <section id="inner-page">
  <div class="inner-page testimonial_page">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php
                    if( get_query_var('page') ) {
  $page = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
  $page = 1;
}
                    $row= 0;
                    $testimonial_per_page  = 1;
                    $testimonials = get_field( 'testimonial_section_data' );
                    $total_testimonials = count( $testimonials );
                    $pages = ceil( $total_testimonials / $testimonial_per_page );
                    $min = ( ( $page * $testimonial_per_page ) - $testimonial_per_page ) + 1;
                    $max = ( $min + $testimonial_per_page ) - 1;
                    if( have_rows('testimonial_section_data',get_the_ID()) ):
                        while( have_rows('testimonial_section_data',get_the_ID()) ) : the_row();
                        $row++;
                        // Ignore this testimonials if $row is lower than $min
                        if($row < $min) { continue; }
                        if($row > $max) { break; } 
                        $testimonial_section_name = get_sub_field('testimonial_section_name');
                        $testimonial_section_comment = get_sub_field('testimonial_section_comment');
                        $testimonial_section_review = get_sub_field('testimonial_section_review');
                        
                    ?>    
                    <div class="testimonial-list">
                            <div class="testimonialpage_main">
                                    <div class="testimonial_quote"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i></div>
                                            <div class="testimonial_text">
                                                <div class="review">
                                                    <?php echo $testimonial_section_review;?>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php echo $testimonial_section_comment;?>
                                                <?php if($testimonial_section_name){?>
                                                <h3>- <?php echo $testimonial_section_name;?></h3>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                         endwhile;
                         echo paginate_links( array(
                                                    'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
                                                    'format' => '?page=%#%',
                                                    'current' => $page,
                                                    'total' => $pages
                            ) );
                    endif;
                    ?>
                   
                    
                    
                   
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>



<?php

get_footer();
```